# Create a list of maps using JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I want to run this query using Spring Jdbctemplate

```
    String sql = "select domain_item_value from domain_item where domain_item_id = 6 and domain_item_id = 9";
    List<Map<String, Object>> odTypeMap = template.query(valQ,  new SingleColumnRowMapper<Map<String, Object>>());
```

The odTypeMap is always empty.
What I expect is a list of Maps as follows.

```
DOMAIN_ITEM_ID->6
DOMAIN_ITEM_VALUE->CURRENT

DOMAIN_ITEM_ID->9
DOMAIN_ITEM_VALUE->AGED
```

What am I doing wrong while running the template.query method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong understanding on how [`SingleColumnRowMapper<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SingleColumnRowMapper.html) works. The generic type is associated with the mapped type of  the column you are trying to represent.

By passing a Map as a type you might be confusing it with [`ColumnMapRowMapper<Map<String, Object>>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ColumnMapRowMapper.html).

Take a look at [this blog post](http://selvam2day.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/singlecolumnrowmapper.html) for example usage and comparison.